# How to display text in a dialog box?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

The Data that I have entered in the input text field of the prime faces data table is not displayed  in the dialog box  JSF file and Data is not displayed in the dialog box

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<title>Add/Remove Row</title>
</h:head>
<body>
<h:form id="form">


<p:dataTable id="buss" value="#{busBean.mediumBusModel}" var="bus"
  selection="#{busBean.selectedBus}" selectionMode="single" >  

   <p:column headerText="Brand" style="width:5%">

         <p:inputText value="#{bus.brand}" />

         </p:column>



      <p:column headerText="Model" style="width:5%">

         <p:inputText value="#{bus.model}" />

         </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Action" style="width:10%">


         <p:commandButton actionListener="#{busBean.addBus()}" icon="ui-icon-plus" update=":form" ajax="false" title="add"/>
         <p:commandButton actionListener="#{busBean.removeBus(bus)}"  icon="ui-icon-minus" update=":form" ajax="false" title="remove"/>
         </p:column>

         <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton id="viewButton" value="View" icon="ui-icon-search"
                             update=":form:displayBus" oncomplete="PF('singleBusDialog').show()"/>
        </f:facet>

    </p:dataTable>
    <br/>

      <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Bus Detail" widgetVar="singleBusDialog" resizable="false"
              showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode">

        <h:panelGrid id="displayBus" columns="2" cellpadding="4">


            <h:outputText value="Brand:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{bus}" style="font-weight:bold"/>

            <h:outputText value="Model:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{bus}" style="font-weight:bold"/>

         </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the bean class that I have used

```
package com.bus.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.UnselectEvent;

import com.bus.bean.Bus;


@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class BusBean implements Serializable {


    private List<Bus> busList;

    private Bus selectedBus;


private BusDataModel mediumBusModel;  



       public BusBean() {

           busList=new ArrayList<Bus>();
           busList.add(new Bus("a","b"));
           mediumBusModel = new BusDataModel(busList);
            //populateRandomCars(cars, 50);


        }

    public List<Bus> getBusList()
    {


        return busList;
    }

    public void setBusList(List<Bus> busList) {
        this.busList = busList;
    }


    public void addBus()
    {
        Bus newBus=new Bus();


        busList.add(newBus);

    }

    public Bus getSelectedBus() {
        return selectedBus;
    }

    public void setSelectedBus(Bus selectedBus) {
        this.selectedBus = selectedBus;
    }

    public void removeBus(Bus bus)
    {
        busList.remove(bus);

    }

    public BusDataModel getMediumBusModel() {
        return mediumBusModel;
    }




}
-------------------------------------------------------
package com.bus.bean;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.model.ListDataModel;
import com.bus.bean.Bus;
import org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel;

public class BusDataModel extends ListDataModel<Bus> implements SelectableDataModel<Bus> {  

    public BusDataModel() {
    }

    public BusDataModel(List<Bus> data) {
        super(data);
    }

    @Override
    public Bus getRowData(String rowKey) {
        //In a real app, a more efficient way like a query by rowKey should be implemented to deal with huge data

        List<Bus> buss = (List<Bus>) getWrappedData();

        for(Bus bus : buss) {
            if(bus.getModel().equals(rowKey))
                return bus;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(Bus bus) {
        return bus.getBrand();
    }
}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------/
package com.bus.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;


public class Bus implements Serializable

{
    public String model;
    public String brand;

    public Bus()
    {

    }

    public Bus(String Model,String Brand)
    {
        this.model = model;
        this.brand = brand;

    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }
    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
    public String getBrand() {
        System.out.println("in set:"+brand);
        return brand;
    }
    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        System.out.println("in set:"+brand);
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj == null)
            return false;

        if(!(obj instanceof Bus))
            return false;

        Bus compare = (Bus) obj;

        return compare.model.equals(this.model);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 1;

        return hash * 31 + model.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bus{" + "model=" + model + ", brand=" + brand + '}';
    }





    enter code here

}
```

Please let me know how to get the data that I have entered in the text field  of Primefaces data table to the dialog box

Answer (score 1):

You should use the selected value from the datatable.

```
selection="#{busBean.selectedBus}"
```

So , in your dialog box

```
        <h:outputText value="Brand:" />
        <h:outputText value="#{busBean.selectedBus.brand}" />
```

Also,

```
<p:commandButton id="viewButton" value="View" icon="ui-icon-search"
                             update=":form:displayBus,:form:dialog" oncomplete="PF('singleBusDialog').show()"/>
```

Updating the dialog box with value of the selected row.

Comment: I have modified the code as per your suggestion still the data is not displayed in the dialog.

Comment: I am entering the data manually in the data table table,after entering the data in the cell I am able to view in the cell but when I select the row and click the view button selected row data is not displayed in the dialog box. please help how to get the data in the dialog box.

Comment: @user3259553 No you can't do that. The data you enter is actually saved to that variable of the datatable (bus). You will need to save the data first then the selected row will have new data.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<title>Add/Remove Row</title>
</h:head>
<body>
<h:form id="form">


<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>

    <p:contextMenu for="buss">   
        <p:menuitem value="Edit Cell" icon="ui-icon-search" onclick="PF('busTable').showCellEditor();return false; "/>  

    </p:contextMenu> 

 <p:dataTable id="buss" var="bus" value="#{busBean.busModel}" editable="true" editMode="cell" widgetVar="busTable" 
 selection="#{busBean.selectedBus}">


  <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{busBean.onCellEdit}" update=":form:messages" /> 

  <p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:2%" />
   <p:column headerText="Brand" style="width:25%">  
               <p:cellEditor>  

                   <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{bus.brand}" /></f:facet>  

                   <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="brandInput" value="#{bus.brand}" style="width:96%"/></f:facet>  
               </p:cellEditor>  
           </p:column> 

            <p:column headerText="Model" style="width:25%">  
               <p:cellEditor>  
                   <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{bus.model}" /></f:facet>  
                   <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{bus.model}" style="width:96%"/></f:facet>  
               </p:cellEditor>  
           </p:column> 




        <p:column headerText="Action" style="width:10%">


         <p:commandButton actionListener="#{busBean.addBus()}" icon="ui-icon-plus" update=":form" ajax="false" title="add"/>
         <p:commandButton actionListener="#{busBean.removeBus(bus)}"  icon="ui-icon-minus" update=":form" ajax="false" title="remove"/>
         </p:column>

         <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton id="viewButton" value="View" icon="ui-icon-search"
                             update=":form:buss,:form:displayBus,:form:dialog" oncomplete="PF('singleBusDialog').show()"/>
        </f:facet>


    </p:dataTable>
    <br/>

      <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Bus Detail" widgetVar="singleBusDialog" resizable="false"
              showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode">

        <h:panelGrid id="displayBus" columns="2" cellpadding="4">


            <h:outputText value="Brand:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{busBean.selectedBus.brand}" style="font-weight:bold"/>

            <h:outputText value="Model:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{busBean.selectedBus.model}"/>
```

Comment: above is the code I am trying still data is not displayed in the dialog box.please help me to get the data I the dialog box that I have entered